# Custom Form with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I want to create a form that work in two ways. i'm going to explain how my models works for now:

i have an user that follow like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :dependency
  has_many :requests

end
```

and a request:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

end
```

in this case we have a user that has many requests and a requests has and belongs to many users. many to many relationship.

So i need to create a form that:

1. Ask for a user_id if it exists then create a relationship into the table requests_users, between that user and the created requests.
2. If the user doesn't exists then use (nested attributes) to create the new user and make a link with the new request and insert a new user in the table users. (This way works for now, but i don't know how to implement the one and considering this 2 in the same form)

for now i have the forms to create an user and associate it to the requests. but i need booth cases. i was checking

```
belongs_to :user, :autosave => true

def autosave_associated_records_for_user
end
```

to ask if user exists first but i don't find the way if doesn't exist show other fields on the form.

please help me to how to solve this or do a solution using ajax or something.

Thanks.

Comment: The solution was add the accepts_nested_attributes_for to the users_requests intermedia table, that handle both.